Where do I find SKAdNetworkIdentifier for the TikTok?
I have to implement SKAdNetwork in my Swift iOS App. I've found SKAdNetworkIdentifier for Facebook from this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/SKAdNetwork/ but I'm not able to find the same for TikTok.
Where am I going wrong? If anyone could guide me, it would be really helpful to me.
Thank you!
